# Extract string between qoutes in a script

Tags: bash, shell, sed, scripting, grep

my text-

```
(
    "en-US"
)
```

what i need -

```
en-US
```

currently im able to get it by piping it with

```
... | tr -d '[:space:]' | sed s/'("'// | sed s/'("'// | sed s/'")'//
```

I wonder if there is a simple way to extract the string between the qoutes rather than chopping off useless parts one by one

Answer (score 2):

`... | grep -oP '(?<=").*(?=")'`

Explanation:

- `-o`: Only output matching string
- `-P`: Use Perl style RegEx
- `(?<=")`: Lookbehind, so only match text that is preceded by a double quote
- `.*`: Match any characters
- `(?=")`: Lookahead, so only match text that is followed by a double quote

Answer (score 2):

With `sed`

```
echo '(
    "en-US"
)' | sed -rn 's/.*"(.*)".*/\1/p'
```

with 2 commands

```
echo '(
    "en-US"
)' | tr -d "\n" | cut -d '"' -f2
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following. Where `var` is the bash variable haveing shown sample value stored in it.

```
echo "$var" | awk 'match($0,/".*"/){print substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2)}'
```

***Explanation:*** Following is only for explanation purposes.

```
echo "$var" |                              ##Using echo to print variable named var and using |(pipe) to send its output to awk command as an Input.
awk '                                      ##Starting awk program from here.
match($0,/".*"/){                        ##using match function of awk to match a regex which is to match from  till next occurrence of "  by this match 2 default variables named RSTART and RLENGTH will be set as per values.
  print substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2)      ##Where RSTART means starting point index of matched regex and RLENGTH means matched regex length, here printing sub-string whose starting point is RSTART and ending point of RLENGTH to get only values between " as per request.
}'                                         ##Closing awk command here.
```

Comment: @R347, Sure added a detailed explanation, kindly do lemme know in case of any queries here, cheers.

Comment: @EdMorton, sure sir, thanks for letting know I changed it now, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using

```
... | grep -o '"[^"]\{1,\}"' | sed -e 's/^"//' -e 's/"$//'
```

`grep` will extract all substrings between quotes (excluding empty ones), the sed later will remove the quotes on both ends.

Answer (score 1):

And this one ?

`... | grep '"' | cut -d '"' -f 2`

It works if you have just 1 quoted value by line.